# How to get the include paths of WDM compiler?

Tags: windows, driver, wdk, wdm

I'm reading the source code of some device driver for Windows XP, and I want to know the exact include paths of the WDM compiler. I know that these should be included :

```
C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\api
C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk
C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\crt
```

But, I know there must be some other paths the WDM build uses. For example, I don't know where the `'__int32'` get defined.

By the way, similarly, I also want to know how to get the library paths the WDM linker needs.

Comment: `__int32` is an integral type, there is no header file for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your driver and look at the build log. All /I flags to cl.exe are include paths, there are no lib paths, all libs are referenced using full paths (which you can see in the log as well).

Doron Holan